# Wcf Use in winform via class library

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-binding

I have a solution in vs2010 that contains some projects:

```
a wcf project
a win form project
a class library
```

My class library has the reference the wcf services. When I try to use this references for retrieve data from wcf in winform app this error was raised:

`Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MikServiceShopInfo.IshopsService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.`

I changed app.config of class library to this:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8855/LaptopsInfoService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILaptopsInfoService"
          contract="ILaptopsInfoService" 
          name="BasicHttpBinding_ILaptopsInfoService" />
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8855/shopsService.svc" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IshopsService"
          contract="IshopsService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IshopsService" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things come to mind:

1. Fully-qualify the contract name in the config file, i.e.:

   contract="MikServiceShopInfo.IshopsService"
2. Copy the `<serviceModel>` section from your app.config for the class library to the config file for your WinForm.  Class libraries do not use config files - they use the config file of the application (website, WinForm, etc) that is referencing them.

Comment: by default fully-qualify contract name exists. i changed it to solve my problem. and i have copied <serviceModel> to my winapp project but problem is still alive.